# Restart a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

i need help with a password program im creating:

```
while len(pw) <= 6 and len(pw) >= 12  is True:
    print ('')
else:
     print ('Please Re-Enter your password, as it must be between 6-12 characters long')
     continue
```

that is my current code, but the continue is outside of the loop so i cannot restart it.

So how can i restart the loop? Thanks!

Comment: Please note that len(pw) can NEVER be less than 7 AND greater than 11, so the body of your while loop will never execute. Please try some basic Python tutorials https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/ or maybe buy a book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pw = ''
while len(pw) < 6 or len(pw) > 12:
    pw = raw_input('Please enter a password between 6-12 characters long: ')
```

This runs as:

```
>>> pw = ''
>>> while len(pw) < 6 or len(pw) > 12:
...     pw = raw_input('Please enter a password between 6-12 characters long: ')
... 
Please enter a password between 6-12 characters long: one
Please enter a password between 6-12 characters long: this is a long sentence
Please enter a password between 6-12 characters long: this works
>>>
```

In the above code, we set `pw` to a string with length 0. Then, until the length matches our requirement (6 - 12 characters), we ask for input.

Or, if you want to use `continue`:

```
>>> while True:
...     pw = raw_input('Please enter a password between 6-12 characters long: ')
...     if len(pw) < 6 or len(pw) > 12:
...             print('Please Re-Enter your password, as it must be between 6-12 characters long')
...             continue
...     break
... 
Please enter a password between 6-12 characters long: one
Please Re-Enter your password, as it must be between 6-12 characters long
Please enter a password between 6-12 characters long: this is a long sentence
Please Re-Enter your password, as it must be between 6-12 characters long
Please enter a password between 6-12 characters long: this works
>>>
```

Your `continue` is outside of the while loop, and you can't 're-enter', so to speak.

Comment: Thanks very much, i feel like a dumbass know :) , that is a much more logical way, thanks!